# problema al enviar un correo con php mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Quiero enviar un correo mediante phpmailer estoy probando para luego colocarle los datos que tendra los correos generados pero me da el siguiente error

> ```
> Extension missing: openssl
> Mailer Error: Extension missing: openssl
> ```

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require './phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->isSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "micorreo@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "micontraseña";
$mail->SetFrom("destinatario@hotmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("micorreo@gmail.com");

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Tienes que verificar que OpenSSL está instalado y activado en tu PHP, desde phpinfo ([ver issue 511 de PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/511)). Si no está activado o instalado, debes hacer una o ambas cosas (en el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/book.openssl.php) está todo indicado.)

Comment: OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
OpenSSL Header Version OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012         es lo que me sale en mi configuración pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: ¿Tienes la versión de OpenSSL de hace 5 años instalada? Entonces es necesario actualizarla, ([página de descargas](https://www.openssl.org/source/)), por motivos de seguridad. En cuanto a PHPMailer, ¿tienes la librería completa instalada?

Comment: si php mailer si esta completo